# Select2 load data from database - CodeIgniter

Tags: php, json, codeigniter

I try to load database data in my Select2 input.  (Im working on CI)

**Here's my code from the controller :** transforms array in echo json

```
class Ajax extends CI_Controller {

public function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('client');
}

public function returnClientsAjax(){
    echo json_encode($this->client->getClients());
}
```

}

**Model :** returning an array of results

```
function getClients(){
    return $this->db->query("SELECT idclient AS id, CONCAT(societe,' [', nom,']') as text FROM du_client WHERE (societe != '' AND nom != '') AND evo2012 >=2 AND type_client != 'Particulier' AND statut_client = 'Demandeur' AND idclient = 6141;")->result_array();
}
```

**My Select2 :**

```
$("#sel_clients").select2({
    placeholder: "Search for an Item",
    ajax: {
        dataType: "json",
        url: "http://commexpert.dev.local/ajax/returnclientsajax",
        results: function (data) {
            return {results: data};
        }
    }
});
```

The input still empty so, don't know what to do.

Thnaks :D

Comment: Check whether you added select2.min.js or Not.

Comment: Yeah i linked the select2 js in there. And the path is good

Comment: `return {results: data};`  here `data` is a complete object, so try by doing something like `return { results: data.id };`

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'slice' of undefined

Answer (score 0):

I think something is missing on your data results method. Here is my code from working ajax select2 component:

```
            results: function (data) {
                var results = [];
                var id1 = data.id;
                var name = data.text;
                $.each(data.data, function(index, item){
                    results.push({
                        id: item[id1],
                        text: item[name].trim()+' : '+ item[id1]
                    });
                });
                return {results: results};
            }
```

also, I'm having somewhat diff data call also:

```
data: function (term) {
    try {
        mirko = $(this).closest('[rendered]').find( "input[fparamname$=" + $(this).attr('flookupfiltref') + "]" ).val();
        if (mirko.indexOf(' : ') >=0 ) { // pocetna vrijednost
            mirko = mirko.split(' : ')[1].trim();
        }
    } catch(e){
        mirko = '';
    }
    return {
        sp_name: $(this).attr('objectname'),
        fl_name: $(this).attr('fparamname'),
        node_id: $(this).attr('node_id'),
        bound: mirko,
        q: term,
    };
},
```

I'm having somekind of manipulation before sending or returning q to server,, but I hope that can help you for your service :)

hth, k